# What does BaseHandler.apply_response_fixes do in django?

Tags: python, django, http-headers, http-redirect

I'm stepping through the django request/response cycle with `pdb` to debug a problem with redirects being mangled.

I'm past the application of middleware in the final stages of the response ([link to django source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/handlers/base.py#L242)) and I get to the point where `BaseHandler.apply_response_fixes(request,response)` is called and it messes with my redirect headers:

**headers before**

```
(Pdb) response._headers
{'x-frame-options': ('X-Frame-Options', 'SAMEORIGIN'), 
'content-type': ('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream'), 
'location':'http://localhost:9000/6/result//blogs/', 
'server': ('Server', 'WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.4.3')}
```

Now I make the next step:

```
-> response = self.apply_response_fixes(request, response)
(Pdb) n
```

And now there is a stray `t` in my location header:

**headers after**

```
(Pdb) response._headers
{'x-frame-options': ('X-Frame-Options', 'SAMEORIGIN'),
 'content-type': ('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream'), 
'location': ('Location', 'http://localhost:9000/6/result//blogs/t'),      
'server': ('Server', 'WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.4.3')}
```

`BaseHandler.apply_response_fixes(request,response)` looks innocous enough :

```
response_fixes = [
    http.conditional_content_removal,
]
def apply_response_fixes(self, request, response):
        """
        Applies each of the functions in self.response_fixes to the request and
        response, modifying the response in the process. Returns the new
        response.
        """
        for func in self.response_fixes:
            response = func(request, response)
        return response
```

What's going on here? What does `BaseHandler.apply_response_fixes(request, response)` do?

How can I circumvent the issue?

Comment: What is the class of your response object ?

Comment: `django.http.HttpResponse`

Comment: Why you don't use an HttpResponseRedirect ? The only thing that I see is that the ``conditional_content_removal`` function called by ``apply_response_fixes`` change the content value of the ``HttpResponse`` object.  And the ``HttpResponse`` has a property setter that make some changes in the response [Code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/http/response.py#L314) . I don't know if it's the source of your problem.

Comment: Yeah me neither. I am not the author of the redirect, I'm proxying it through so I can't do anything about the base class.